# Need help to bulkify my after insert trigger code

Tags: apex

Hi I need help to bulkify my code, as of now I have a for loop inside a foor loop that Iterates User id and pass it to create a task, I can't seem to think of a way where In I won't need the for loop inside the for loop. I was thinking for using a Map but I would also need to for loop that one to iterate the values.

As you can see, document object has no relation to user and task, this was supposed to be a workflow but the thing is you can only assign one user using worlflow task creation, that's when I decided to use Trigger.

ORRRRRRRRRR I'm just overthinking and my code is fine? Need help guys.

This is the Method that I need help to.

```
        Set<Id> userId = new Set<Id>();
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    Set<Id> recordTypeId = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> documentId = new Set<Id>();

    for(PatientConnect__PC_Document__c pd : newList){
        documentId.add(pd.Id);
    }

    RecordType rc = [SELECT Id , Name FROM RecordType WHERE name =: PC_Roche_Constants.PSP_TASK_RECORD_TYPE_NAME];

    //get user Id of user with Role TH CC Manager and TH CC
    for(User us : [SELECT Id, UserRole.Name, PC_Roche_Affiliate__c FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name =: PC_Roche_Constants.TH_CC_MANAGER_ROLE OR
                  UserRole.Name =: PC_Roche_Constants.TH_CARE_Coordinator]){
        userId.add(us.Id);
    }

    for(PatientConnect__PC_Document__c pd : [Select Id,RecordType.Name , PC_Roche_Affiliate__c from PatientConnect__PC_Document__c where Id =: documentId]){
        //Validate Document Recordtype is Online Form and Affiliate TH
        if(pd.RecordType.Name == PC_Roche_Constants.DOCUMENT_SMARTFORM_RECORD_TYPE_NAME && pd.PC_Roche_Affiliate__c == PC_Roche_Constants.AFFILIATE_TH){
            //Iterate userId's to be inserted
            for(Id assignedToId : userId){
                //Create Task
                Task tsk = new Task(OwnerId = assignedToId,
                                   RecordTypeId = rc.Id,
                                   Status = PC_Roche_Constants.PC_STATUS_NOT_STARTED,
                                   Priority = PC_Roche_Constants.MEDIUM_PRIORITY,
                                   ActivityDate = System.today(),
                                   WhatId = pd.Id,
                                   Subject = PC_Roche_Constants.NEW_PATIENT_REGISTRATION
                                   );
                taskList.add(tsk);
            }
        }
    }

    insert taskList; 
    System.debug('TASKLIST>>>>>' + taskList);
```

Comment: Creating tasks and adding them to a list that will be inserted outside from a loop it's completely fine. I think you might be overthinking it, as you said. The issue would be if you had dml operations or SOQL queries inside. Obviously every time you can avoid for loops nestes one another you try to do so. In this case since you seem to want to assign a task to each user in the Set seems fine to me.

Comment: As far as there is no SOQL/DML inside a loop it's fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just one optimization left for your code, and it's not bulkification. The query could handle the if statement so you query fewer records and improve CPU/Query usage.

```
for(PatientConnect__PC_Document__c pd : [
  Select Id PC_Roche_Affiliate__c 
  from PatientConnect__PC_Document__c 
  where Id =: documentId and 
   RecordType.Name = :PC_Roche_Constants.DOCUMENT_SMARTFORM_RECORD_TYPE_NAME and 
   PC_Roche_Affiliate__c = :PC_Roche_Constants.AFFILIATE_TH]){
    //Iterate userId's to be inserted
    for(Id assignedToId : userId){
        //Create Task
        Task tsk = new Task(OwnerId = assignedToId,
                           RecordTypeId = rc.Id,
                           Status = PC_Roche_Constants.PC_STATUS_NOT_STARTED,
                           Priority = PC_Roche_Constants.MEDIUM_PRIORITY,
                           ActivityDate = System.today(),
                           WhatId = pd.Id,
                           Subject = PC_Roche_Constants.NEW_PATIENT_REGISTRATION
                           );
        taskList.add(tsk);
    }
}
```